# Do Americans pronounce "do you" as something like "dia" or "d'ya"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent

I heard some Americans talking and they said something like **dia/d'ya** instead of **do you.**

For example:

> What time do you have

was said something like

> what time dia/d'ya have

is that correct please?

Comment: That is a fairly accurate phonetic spelling of  how "do you" is pronounced in *casual* American speech.  But "d' ya" might be closer. The "i" in "dia" is not [I].

Comment: Well, it's impossible to tell precisely what pronunciation the OP intends, but it seems like it might be reasonable.  But yes, *do* has a proclitic form that appears before *you* in clauses with subject-auxiliary inversion, one which usually isn't indicated in writing.

Comment: Really? I knew exactly what he meant, as if I were reading his mind.

Comment: d ya is what i meant, i typed dia instead of d ya because i am not good in explaning my idea

Comment: @TRomano Of course not.  That's the problem with this sort of ad hoc transcription system―people can be fooled into believing they're communicating when they're imagining two different things.  There are multiple possible pronunciations here, and you have no idea which one he intends.  (An answerer can clear this up by describing the possibilities―there's certainly enough information here to write an answer.)

Comment: Practically all native speakers routinely reduce ***do you*** in many contexts. Exactly how *much* they reduce it varies by speaker and context. But nobody transcribes any version using ***dia*** - the most common form is [***D'ya** {wanna know how it's normally written?}*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22d%27ya+wanna%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) On the other hand, although we often reduce ***do we*** in exactly the same way, it's very unusual to see this written as ***D'we*** or anything similar.

Comment: The usefulness of the answer for most people who would ask does not require careful coding nor fine and careful technical descriptions. A person with a trained ear can listen to (or recall) what the words usually sound like together, and easily see what someone would mean if they say (or ask if) it sounds like *dia, d'ya, dahya, deyah* or similar, as contrasted with *do you,* and have it make good practical sense.

Comment: In fact, snailboat is correct that there are multiple possible pronunciations, depending on grammar pattern and other factors. But (as TRomano suggests), it's safe for many of us to get, at a gross level, what's being asked, and to answer in the "language", at the "level", that the OP asks.

Comment: @TRomano could you give me please any link about these stuff you wrote? like the *charector* after D and before ya in D'ya

Comment: The *apostrophe* ['] indicates that a letter (corresponding to a sound) has been dropped.  *do you* becomes *d' ya* to indicate that the 'oo' sound (oo = u in Italian *i musici*)  has been "swallowed up" or dropped. The 'oo' sound in "you" (italian *iu*) becomes "yuh" or "ya" which is meant to represent a sound like the first "o" in italian *bottone*.

Comment: The reason why we don't write *D' we wanna do this?* is because the -w- sound requires the lips to be pursed ( double u, uu) which is exactly where the lips would be with 'Do', so "we" actually extends the 'oo' sound, unlike 'ya', which requires the lips to be protracted to produce the palatal [j].

Comment: Retracted, that is.

Comment: @TRomano thanks, because of your comments, i noticed for the very first time that Google Translate uses these *characters* when trying to say the words, and I found that there are many of them, could you give me the official names for these *characters* please? and if you have links to study them, i would appreciate it

Comment: International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA). https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/content/full-ipa-chart

Comment: Since no one's mentioned it, I'll give one reason why the pronunciation of *d'you* varies: **yod coalescence**.  The /dj/ sequence optionally turns into /dʒ/ here, or into something in between the two.  Another reason is the reduction of the vowel to schwa, which is also optional.  So there are a great many possible pronunciations of *d'you* in American English.

Comment: This is certainly not limited to *American* English. See the BBC's [Sounds of English, programme 3](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/multimedia/pron/progs/prog3.shtml), especially the last example, which includes examples of *you* coming after a *D*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In the standard American accent, Americans usually say *do you* something like *dia* sounds in Italian.

But the *i* sound would be shorter and softer than the Italian *i* sound.

Native English speakers and others with a basic sense of English spelling and pronunciation would likely use *d'ya* or similar to convey the kind of sound we can guess you have perceived.

An expert could provide a great deal of technical information, but that would seemingly be more useful in a different forum and/or in response to a question differently styled.

Comment: In my innocence, I tried `dia` on Google Translate. I selected Italian, listened to how it sounds like, and I think it doesn't sound anything like English "D'ya" at all.

Comment: The forest is being missed for the trees. Suppose the question had been: It seems that I've heard "do you" pronounced quite differently than what rhymes with *too too.* Is there quite a difference? I feel quite confident I could answer "yes", and have a fundamental handle on what he heard and why he asked, regardless of how anyone would encode it (them!)

Comment: But you know me (I hope!), and if you trust me, I think (hope) you'll believe me if I say that what we (English learners) think we hear and what we actually hear aren't always the same.

Comment: I then suspect that an ELL would begin pronouncing the word pair more similarly to what he perceived. He would also ne primed to attend more carefully to the sounds Americans make when we pronounce it, and get even closer, then learn further differentiation. Mostly quite usefully on his own with little guidance, and for most of us, the simpler that guidance the better.

Comment: I do, and I also trust that the OP heard something interesting to him, and that he doesn't want a technical response. He wants some confirmation that he heard something like "xxxx". And we can usefully "confirm" it, however a hearer might decide to try to code it. And Google can't speak Italian because it doesn't have hands. O.O

Comment: There's no one standard American pronounciation.  "D'ya" might be a fairly accurate representation of how some groups would pronounce "do you" - I've often seen it in writing about New York City, for instance.  Around here (intermountain west) it seems more like two distinct words: "doo yoo".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Americans do this, but it is not only an American phenomenon. Read the [Wikipedia article on the song "D'yer Mak'er"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27yer_Mak%27er), which is meant to be pronounced the same as "Jamaica".